# Yesod and docker-compose logs in development mode

Tags: docker-compose, yesod

I have a Yesod application running through docker and docker-compose but when I want to watch logs, I have a timeout after 60 seconds...
I think this is due to yesod devel command which is interactive.

I've tried with this docker-compose configuration :

```
version: '2'
services:
  yesod:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: stack exec -- yesod devel
```

But when I use `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose logs -f yesod`, it return this message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 61, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 113, in perform_command
  File "contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
  File "compose/cli/errors.py", line 56, in handle_connection_errors
TypeError: log_timeout_error() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
docker-compose returned -1
```

Here is my Dockerfile for this service :

```
FROM haskell:7

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app

RUN stack install cabal-install
RUN stack install
RUN stack install yesod-bin
```

If you have any advice on how to avoid this timeout when watching logs, I'm all ears and will be eternaly thankful...

Comment: Which version of docker-compose are you using? That stacktrace was probably fixed in a newer version.

Comment: I'm using last version : 1.8.0 !

Comment: @dnephin: Oh, it wasn't last build...
I've updated my docker-compose to last version and now, no stack-trace, just this message :

    ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
    If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3106) when using `tty: true`.  Do you actually need a `tty` when running `up`?

Comment: I think it was required when I set up this application, but not anymore obviously, but I get same error at the end !

Comment: You might need to restart the docker engine or docker machine. I'm not sure why you're hitting the timeout.